# resizing list components upon dataProvider change

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4, flex4.5, flex-spark

I have a component that contains a list that implements a custom renderer.  I use this component as a tooltip, keeping one in memory and just altering the databindings as necessary.

Something like this where TTComponent is a class that extends Canvas:

```
<s:TTComponent>
  <s:BorderContainer>
    <s:List id='lstItems' dataProvider="{data.Items}" width="50%" borderVisible="false" contentBackgroundColor="#222222">
      <s:layout>
        <s:VerticalLayout useVirtualLayout="false" requestedMinRowCount="1"/>
      </s:layout>
      <s:itemRenderer>
        <fx:Component>
          <s:ItemRenderer>
            <s:HGroup>
              <s:Label text="{data.Value}" paddingLeft="6" />
              <s:Label text="{data.Name}" />
            </s:HGroup>
          </s:ItemRenderer>
        </fx:Component>
      </s:itemRenderer>
    </s:List>        
  </s:BorderContainer>
</s:TTComponent>
```

Now, the driver code looks like this for the mouse over:

```
if (tt == null) {
  tt = new TTComponent();
}
tt.data = data;
PopUpManager.addPopUp(tt, this);
```

And, of course, the mouse out:

```
PopUpManager.removePopUp(tt);
```

Now, what happens is when data containing many items is set to tt.data, the list resizes itself larger and displays fine.  However, after this, if data containing few items is set to tt.data, the component momentarily displays larger than it needs to be, then resizes itself smaller.

What I'd like to do is have the component resize itself before it displays, so I don't see the resize on screen. Any idea on how to accomplish this?

Comment: Where do you set the size of the toolTip?  Where do change the size of it?  Or does it change automatically?  It also strikes me as unusual to mix mc components (Canvas) with spark components.

Comment: Mixing the components seems to work fine.  The size is determined automatically.

Comment: Mixing component sets often does work fine, but it is unusual approach, especially in your case where a group can probably easily replace the Canvas.  "The size is determined automatically" probably means that some code in one of the components you're using is determine the size.  You have to find that code and override it.  In this case, I might take a look at the measure method of the "TTComponent".

Comment: No, I don't believe so.  I wrote all of the code myself, nowhere is the height specified.  How does your suggestion help resize the component prior to display after altering the data binding?  I'm not following your reasoning.

Comment: In your code, I see a half dozen or so Flex Framework components, which I suspect contain a significant amount of code that you did not write yourself.  Flex containers make use of the Flex Component LifeCycle methods to size and position their children.  I believe somewhere in that code, the pop-up is being sized.  If I had to guess; reworking the measure method of your custom Canvas would solve the issue.  But, I'm just guessing. Since you aren't setting an explicit size; usually the 'parent' of the component will decide what size to make it--using the measuredHeight and measuredWidth values

Comment: Yes, I get all that.  Obviously something is doing the resizing, since I haven't specified it anywhere.  But exactly how will reworking the measure method of the custom class allow me to hide the component prior to display?  It seems to me that you may be missing the objective here.  The component is resizing properly.  I just don't want the user to see the component until the resize has already occurred.

Comment: In theory, in the reworked measure method you will define a new "ideal size" of the pop up as part of the component lifecycle; and therefore as part of the same render event that changes the list after the dataProvider changes; thus causing no "staggered" visual resize; but rather resizing everything in one swoop.

Answer (score 0):

First, I would compel you to consider creating the component once and just showing / hiding it / moving it when needed rather than using pop up manager.  That's how I would typically do something similar to what you're attempting.  It will perform better and probably fix this issue on its own.  Just a thought.

Secondly, after you rebind new data to it, try these :

Tell it needs to resize :

```
tt.invalidateDisplayList();
```

Also, you might need to tell it you changed the data by refreshing the data if an ArrayCollection:

```
data.refresh();
```

Let me know if that doesn't do the trick.

Comment: The power of Nate compels me.  If I knew how to do what you're suggesting, I would.  How do you display impromptu windows and such without using the popup manager?

Comment: By the way, the tt.invalidateDisplayList() did not work.  I could not find a data.refresh() call either.